# ProcessBuilder won't run with arguments

Tags: java, arguments, processbuilder

I am trying to run "java -version" using ProcessBuilder:

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java -version");
process = processBuilder.start();
```

However I get an error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java -version": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

When I remove the "-version" and do:

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java");
process = processBuilder.start();
```

it runs fine and I get the normal help guide output.

How can I get it to run the argument too?

Comment: Sorry! I did try searching for a similar question to this but I hadn't tried searching for "parameter"..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The complete argument is being interpreted as the executable. Use

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-version");
```

Comment: Thanks! I really should've just checked the docs :S

Comment: @user2513924 Yes, you [should have done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

> ## Constructor Summary
>
> ProcessBuilder(List command) - Constructs a process builder with the specified operating system program and arguments.
>
> ProcessBuilder(String... command) - Constructs a process builder with the specified operating system program and arguments.

So you need to use:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-version");
```

Answer (score -2):

You are probably making this unnecessarily complicated. If all you want to do is find out the version of Java you are running on, use `System.getProperty("java.specification.version")`.

Also, your code will fail if Java is not on the PATH, but this way will still work.