# Calling a command line program in Java

Tags: java

I am making a GUI for a command line program using JavaFX.

If I just pack the program inside the .JAR, can I call it? Or do I need to extract the program into the local machine first before making a process? I ask because since a .JAR is a ZIP file, I suppose you can't just run a file inside the .JAR because it is compressed or something.

Comment: The command line program that you want to launch, is it a Java program? Or like a native binary?

Comment: @aioobe native binary

Comment: Then it's the operating system that launches the program. Unless the operating system in question is able to launch programs from within zip-files (which I doubt) you would have to extract the binary and write it to disk before launching.

Comment: this is a good question and I can imagine future visitors struggling with a similar use case so I took the time to write an exhaustive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do this in two steps:

1. Extract the binary and write it to disk (because the OS is probably only able to launch the program if it's a file on disk)
2. Launch the program, preferably using `ProcessBuilder`.

### Here's a complete demo:

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Test.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Path binary = Paths.get("mybinary");
        Files.copy(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("mybinary"), binary);

        System.out.println("Launching external program...");

        // Needed for Linux at least
        Files.setPosixFilePermissions(binary,
                Collections.singleton(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE));

        Process p = new ProcessBuilder("./mybinary").inheritIO().start();
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("External program finished.");
    }
}
```

**Demo**

```
$ cc mybinary.c -o mybinary
$ ./mybinary
Hello world
$ javac Test.java
$ jar -cvf Test.jar Test.class mybinary
$ rm mybinary Test.class
$ ls
mybinary.c  Test.jar  Test.java
$ java -cp Test.jar Test
Launching external program...
Hello world
External program finished.
```

**Further reading:**

- [Run external program concurrently and communicate with it through stdin / stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591215/run-external-program-concurrently-and-communicate-with-it-through-stdin-stdout)
- [How to make an executable jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file)
- [Where does Java's ProcessBuilder look to execute commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368666/where-does-javas-processbuilder-look-to-execute-commands)
- [ProcessBuilder won't run with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346031/processbuilder-wont-run-with-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract your program first to let the os execute it. There's no way to 'stream' it to ram and execute from there.